# How can i reproduce this procedure to CQL (Cassandra)?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, cassandra

i have this procedure and now some how i need reproduce this procedure from SQL, to CQL, can you please help me? If Cassandra have same as procedures in SQL or not? And if not, how i can set variables for this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DeleteOldTransactionLogs]
    @p_daysback INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE 
     @r         int 
    ,@i         int
    ,@maxLogId  int
    ,@billion   int = 1000000000
    ,@deleted   int;


SET @r = 1;
SET @i = 1;
SET @deleted = 0;
 
SELECT 
    @maxLogId = MAX(ictransactionlogid)
FROM dbo.ictransactionLog WITH (INDEX(IX_ictransactionLog_time))
WHERE
    time < DATEADD(day, @p_daysback, GETDATE());

WHILE @r > 0 AND @i <= 7
BEGIN

  DELETE TOP (5000) -- this will change
    dbo.ictransactionLog
    WHERE ictransactionlogid <= @maxLogId;
 
  SET @r = @@ROWCOUNT;
  SET @deleted = @deleted + @r;

  set @i = @i + 1;
END

SELECT @maxLogId = IDENT_CURRENT( 'ictransactionLog' );

 IF @maxLogId > @billion
        BEGIN
            delete from ictransactionLog
            where ictransactionlogid < 500000000
   
            DBCC CHECKIDENT ('ictransactionLog', RESEED, 0);
        END

SELECT @deleted;
END
```

Comment: This is too vague. Start with a simple attempt to modify one portion to see what you can find out.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to do that in the CQL.  There is only limited for user-defined functions & user-defined aggregates, and even they are quite limited.

You need to implement that as a code in some language, such as, Python, etc.